# ALSA - route front left to rear, Center/LFE and adjust volume individually for each channel

Tags: alsa

I dont know if it's even possible, but i would like to route the sound from the front speakers to the rear speaker and still be able to control the volume for each channel individually.

I have an usb sound card with 3 lines out, FRONT, REAR and Center/LFE.

I have figured out how to route the sound from front to rear, Center/LFE speakers in /etc/asound.conf. After alot of time on google i still dont know how to control the volume for front,rear and center/LFE speakers individually.

I use the following asound.conf to route from front speakers.

```
pcm.!default {
    type             softvol
    slave.pcm       "20to51"
    control {
        name "softMixer" # This name is used in mopidy config
        card 0
    }
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}

pcm.20to51 {
  type route
  slave.pcm surround51
  slave.channels 6
  ttable.0.0 1
  ttable.1.1 1
  ttable.0.2 1
  ttable.1.3 1
  ttable.0.4 0.5
  ttable.1.4 0.5
  ttable.1.5 0.5
  ttable.0.5 0.5
}
```

Any ideas on how to adjust each channel individually?

EDIT:
Content from amixer scontents

```
Simple mixer control 'Speaker',0
  Capabilities: pvolume pswitch pswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right - Rear Left - Rear Right - Front Center - Woofer - Side Left - Side Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 197
  Mono:
  Front Left: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Front Right: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Rear Left: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Rear Right: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Front Center: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Woofer: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Side Left: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
  Side Right: Playback 4 [2%] [-36.19dB] [off]
Simple mixer control 'PCM',0
  Capabilities: cvolume cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Capture 0 - 6928
  Front Left: Capture 5543 [80%] [5.65dB] [on]
  Front Right: Capture 5543 [80%] [5.65dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'PCM Capture Source',0
  Capabilities: enum
  Items: 'Mic' 'Line' 'IEC958 In' 'Mixer'
  Item0: 'Mic'
Simple mixer control 'Front Master',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 255
  Front Left: 0 [0%]
  Front Right: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'Line',0
  Capabilities: pvolume cvolume pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 8065 Capture 0 - 6928
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-24.00dB] [off] Capture 4096 [59%] [0.01dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-24.00dB] [off] Capture 4096 [59%] [0.01dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'Mic',0
  Capabilities: pvolume cvolume pswitch pswitch-joined cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: Playback 0 - 8065 Capture 0 - 6928
  Front Left: Playback 0 [0%] [-24.00dB] [off] Capture 0 [0%] [-16.00dB] [on]
  Front Right: Playback 0 [0%] [-24.00dB] [off] Capture 0 [0%] [-16.00dB] [on]
Simple mixer control 'IEC958 In',0
  Capabilities: cswitch cswitch-joined penum
  Capture channels: Mono
  Mono: Capture [on]
Simple mixer control 'SoftMaster',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 255
  Front Left: 0 [0%]
  Front Right: 0 [0%]
Simple mixer control 'softMixer',0
  Capabilities: volume penum
  Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Capture channels: Front Left - Front Right
  Limits: 0 - 255
  Front Left: 240 [94%]
  Front Right: 240 [94%]
```

Comment: The `softvol` plugin does not support more than two channels. If you device does not have per-channel mixer controls, this is not possible.

Comment: Hi, im pretty sure it does have mixer control pr. channel.. Maybe i dont need to create a softvol to route the sound from front to rear ?

Comment: Show the output of `amixer scontents`.

Comment: Added output to my post.

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out

```
pcm.!default {
        type plug
        slave.pcm "ch2to5"
}

pcm.digitalhw {
        type hw
        card 0
}

pcm.ch2to5 {
        type route
        slave.pcm "digitalhw"
        slave.channels 6
        ttable.0.0 1
        ttable.1.1 1
        ttable.0.2 1
        ttable.1.3 1
        ttable.0.4 0.5
        ttable.1.4 0.5
        ttable.1.5 0.5
        ttable.0.5 0.5
}

ctl.!default {
        type hw
        card 0
}
```

With this config, the front sound is routed to rear and LFE/Center, and i can use alsamixer to control the volume for each channel.